# To do lists in project management

Tags: project-management, project-planning

I'm not sure if this an appropriate question for stack overflow. If not, I apologize.

I was wondering if there is any tool for keeping track of different uncompleted tasks in different modules of a project. I'm currently interning at a company and I feel like everytime something cannot be solved immediately, someone asks me to put a 'todo comment', and that task eventually gets forgotten. I was wondering if there's a better way to keep track of stuff like this.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice of you to vote on the answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is an issue tracking system that you can use for this purpose, but you have to enter manually each ticket into the system, but once you're get used to it, it is very useful and effective.

Any issue tracker system also works.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will keep track of comments with `// TODO` in it. There is a "tasks" window which will list them all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Post-Its for each Task. You can also use Kanban to manage those tasks. It's very easy to learn and adapt to your needs.

You can split a whiteboard into some sections like Backlog (for pending and new tasks), Work in Progress (you limit the number of possible concurrent tasks), Deliver/Deploy (almost done), Done.

If you want a computer tool, there are lots of them. Just google for Kanban software.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/hiranabe-lean-agile-kanban

Answer (score 1):

Lots if IDEs will keep track of // TODO comments if that's the route you want to take.

To keep track of todo items outside of and IDE, you can try [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/)

It's free.

Answer (score 1):

Pivotal Tracker looks quite nice as project management tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the CodeProject [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx) to AbstractSpoon's ToDo List

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like whichever system you're using at the moment (if you're using one at all) does not make to-do lists a priority or put to-dos/tasks in your view every morning that you log in.

Sounds like you need something that:

- Allows you to assign different tasks/to-dos to different modules of a project
- Keeps an organized view of which task/to-do has been assigned to which project
- Sets alerts for each separate to-do/task (due date, percent completed, etc)
- Keeps the tasks/to-dos easily viewable (from the dashboard, or put in a prioritized view as soon as you open a project)

A company that I do contract work with, WORKetc, can do all of this. On top of this, they have a huge amount of other project management features, to name a few:

- Collaboration on all aspects of a project
- Unlimited sub projects
- Gantt charts
- Project dependancy
- Timesheet/milestone billing
- To-dos, tasks, easily assignable to specific people/specific projects/specific sub projects, with necessary alerts

The cool thing about WORKetc is on top of being a project managemement tool, WORKetc also has CRM and billing features. It is essentially a total business management platform and that way if you're using other CRM or billing software you can get rid of it entirely, and not have to worry about integrating seperate projects. Even if you don't use these features, I bet its still a better bargain than the majority of the other ones you'll see!

Pricing/website link: http://www.worketc.com/sign_up